# Hotkeys not working on ZAReason laptop in CentOS 8

Tags: hotkeys, input-device, centos-8

I was rather excited to put a new SSD into my [ZAReason](https://zareason.com/Laptops/) laptop and install CentOS 8.

After everything else is working great, I noticed that the hot buttons above my keyboard do not work other than the "enable/disable wifi" button.  Thus, I cannot eject the CD/DVD drive, nor activate/disable the built-in webcam.

I reached out to ZAReason support, but did not receive a reply-- thus, here I am.

From `less /proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="MSI WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=1000300000000 300000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
```

Comment: You called them at 510-868-5000 and they did not respond?

Comment: I submitted a support request, but did not call them.  I'll try doing so on Monday.